# Android Alert dialog from inside an intent service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog, intentservice

I want to display an alert dialog from inside an intent service.

```
   AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

This throws the following exception

```
   Unable to add window — token null is not for an application
```

I have tried IntentService.this and getApplicationContext() as well. Between i dont want to do it using an activity. I just want to show a simple alert dialog with a little text.

Comment: visit https://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/

Comment: visit also https://github.com/selmantayyar/Custom-SMS-Popup

Comment: possible duplicate of [android alert dialog from service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599563/android-alert-dialog-from-service)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804684/2149195

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Need `Activity` for display `AlertDialog`, because we can't display `Dialog` from any `Service`

**Solution.**

Create `Activity` as Dialog Theme and start that `Activity` from `Service`.

Just need to register you `Activity` in `menifest.xml` like as below

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

**MyDialog.java**

```
public class MyDialog extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("your title");
        alertDialog.setMessage("your message");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Didnt want to use activity but it seems like its the only way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also add intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); while before starting activity

Comment: works like sharm using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` , with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` after closing dialog it reapear title in other popup dialog

Answer (score 11):

Only if you set your alertDialog type to `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` it will be displayed from an intent service.

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

add these after your code:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
alertDialog.show();
```

But, it have a cost:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Comment: Didn't work for me in Lollipop. `alertDialog.show()` is called but nothing happens. Yes, I have set the permission - before I did that, it raised an exception, and now it does nothing.

Comment: Found the problem! Because this is running in an IntentService the dialog is destroyed as soon as `onHandleIntent` ends, which is almost immediately after the `alertDialog.show`. It happens so fast you don't even see it flash on the screen. The solution is to either use a Service (rather than IntentService) or this long running IntentService: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841212/can-an-intentservice-run-indefinitely

Answer (score 1):

Please visit

https://github.com/selmantayyar/Custom-SMS-Popup

it will surly help you!!

or what you can do is register anActivity in menifest.xml as follows

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

and work around it

Comment: I was just trying to avoid using an activity. but i finally decided to use it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -2):

The problem is because of **Context**. You can't use **this** as Context in Intent Service. So need to pass a Context variable of your Intent Service to your Alert Dialog. Like,

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
```

Comment: AlertDialog need **Activity** (Activity's context) and there is not activity's context in service.