# How to use alertDialog in background service

Tags: android, android-service, android-alertdialog

I need to prompt a alertDialog in a background service, but it crashed by the bad context, how can I handle it, where I can get the right Context?

Comment: you need the activity context to display alert dialog

Comment: I don't want any activity except background service.

Comment: use a toast to display message

Comment: you can try this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627184/android-alert-dialog-from-inside-an-intent-service

Comment: @LeonLeung, have you solved problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code inside **Service** class to **open AlertDialog**

```
private void showAlertDialog() {

        KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
            kl.disableKeyguard();

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK| PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                    | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
            wakeLock.acquire();


        final CharSequence[] items = { getString(R.string.test1), getString(R.string.tes2), getString(R.string.test3), getString(R.string.cancel) };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals(getString(R.string.test1))) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                } else if (items[item].equals(getString(R.string.test2))) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                } else if (items[item].equals(getString(R.string.test3))) {

                }else if (items[item].equals(getString(R.string.cancel))) {
                    dialog.dismiss();


                }
            }
        });

        alert = builder.create();
        alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alert.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);


        alert.show();

        alert.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {

            }
        });


        alert.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

            }
        });


    }
```

You have to **add permissions** in **Manifest** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

You can do **customize** on alert dialog as your requirements.

**Done**

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer would not work in Oreo+
Please use the flag TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY instead of TYPE_PHONE or SYSTEM_ALERT in WindowManager.LayoutParams:
use

> WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY

instead

> WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT

still the overlay dont show? then check if your app has the permission

Settings.canDrawOverlays() if this is false then.

**User should have this permission too!**
This was introduced in Marshmallow

// Check if Android M or higher

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

// Show alert dialog to the user saying a separate permission is 
 needed
    // Launch the settings activity if the user prefers
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1、you must set:`mDialog.getWindow().setType(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);`
2、 set permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```